# Trouble with loading AmCharts: ERR FILE NOT FOUND

Tags: javascript, svg, google-chrome-extension, amcharts

I'm making a Chrome Extension where I use AmCharts.
The chart does not load and I get the following errors.

> imglens.svg:1 GET chrome-extension://cdjjnkkllgppipkdeobjempdfnafkjcm/charts/imglens.svg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>
> imgdragIconRoundBig.svg:1 GET chrome-extension://cdjjnkkllgppipkdeobjempdfnafkjcm/charts/imgdragIconRoundBig.svg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

However I looked through the AmCharts folder . No such files exist.
What should do I do?

**Code Snippet**

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
"type": "serial",
"valueAxes": [ {
"position": "left"
} ],
"graphs": [ {
"id": "g1",
"balloonText": "Open:<b>[[open]]</b><br>Low:<b>[[low]]</b><br>High:<b>[[high]]</b><br>Close:<b>[[close]]</b><br>",
"proCandlesticks": pro,
"closeField": "close",
"fillColors": "#117e1a",
"highField": "high",
"lineColor": "#117e1a",
"lineAlpha": 1,
"lowField": "low",
"fillAlphas": 0.9,
"negativeFillColors": "#7b1111",
"negativeLineColor": "#7b1111",
"openField": "open",
"title": "Price:",
"type": "candlestick",
"valueField": "close"
} ],

"chartScrollbar": {
"graph": "g1",
"graphType": "line",
"scrollbarHeight": 30
},
"chartCursor": {
"valueLineEnabled": true,
"valueLineBalloonEnabled": true
},
"categoryField": "date",
"categoryAxis": {
"parseDates": true
},
  "dataProvider": data,/*
   "responsive": {
"enabled": true
},*/
"pathToImages": "/charts/img"
},2000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try re-downloading the amcharts zip file. All those files exist in the `amcharts/images/` folder. `pathToImages` needs to point to the folder where the chart icons and images are stored if you moved those files to a different folder (by default it looks in the images folder). You'll need the trailing slash as well if you're using a different path (i.e. `/charts/img/`)

[image: images folder contents]

Comment: I tried the very same . And the files that are not found are imglens.svg and imgdragIconRoundBig.svg  which are not there in the image you posted above. Some of the image files in the above picture and in the downloaded directory have been added with pathToImages and those work.

Comment: The file is supposed to be `lens.svg`, not `imglens.svg` (same for the dragIconRoundBig file). LIke I said, you need the trailing slash in your pathToImages. `img` is being appended because your path lacks a trailing slash. If you add the slash, you'll get `chart/img/lens.svg` which should work.

Comment: Now I get these errors.
>lens.svg Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>dragIconRoundBig.svg Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: ok i tried charts/img/ and /charts/img/ , the latter resolved the errors but the chart still fails to load.

Comment: Do you have any errors? Post your chart data that you're using for the dataProvider.

Comment: No errors. The data is huge I'm acquiring from a [API]( https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=BTC_XMR&start=1405699200&end=9999999999&period=86400)

Comment: Outside of the timestamps being in seconds (amcharts needs them in milliseconds or you'll get dates in 1970 ), the data works fine with your config. Here's a fiddle with a subset of it: https://jsfiddle.net/rr710djL/. Did you set any dimensions for your chart div? You have to specify a width and height in CSS. You'll also want to set an appropriate [`minPeriod`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#minPeriod) that represents the intervals in your dataset.

Comment: It works now! Just needed to adjust some CSS thanks!

Comment: If  you edit your answer to `/charts/img/` I'll accept the answer

Comment: You're welcome. Answer updated with the working path.